# Does "TUNED_BOOT_CMDLINE" /etc/tuned/bootcmdline overwrite BOOT_IMAGE of /proc/cmdline?

Tags: linux-kernel, grub2, boot-loader, tuned

TuneD tool provides an option to configure kernel command line via `TUNED_BOOT_CMDLINE` variable of the `/etc/tuned/bootcmdline`, which is not done directly but via setting a desired TuneD performance profile.

However, there is a direct way to set GRUB command line via `BOOT_IMAGE` variable within `/proc/cmdline`, which as I understand serves the same purpose.

The question is which of the settings has precedence? I mean does TuneD setting overwrite, extends or gets overruled by the one of GRUB?

I tried to find an answer by crawling the Internet, but have no luck so far. I prefer not to rely on an empirical testing, as I need to understand how it really works and not how it appears to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments into the [TuneD code](https://github.com/redhat-performance/tuned/blob/master/tuned/plugins/plugin_bootloader.py) could give the answer, in particular :

```
    NOTE: *TuneD* will not remove or replace kernel command line
    parameters added via other methods like *grubby*. *TuneD* will manage
    the kernel command line parameters added via *TuneD*.
```

Comments from which I understand that TuneD settings can only have precedence over previous TuneD settings. And that whatever parameter set in the boot command line by any other method will keep precedence over TuneD settings.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise answer. From the comments in the code, it looks like the actual final version of the kernel command-line is a merger of several possible sources (not only GRUB or TuneD). How does one see the final version of the kernel command-line merged from all the sources?

Comment: @Arsenly : *"How does one see the final version of the kernel command-line"* Does *dmesg | grep command* answer your question ?

Comment: yes absolutely. It's incredibly simple and does exactly what's needed.